# Connecting Content with Mobile Push API

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, marketingcloudapi

We are anlysing on implemention Mobile Push API to send transactional messages via Mobile app. I have a question in this regard.

Does anyone know , when we make an API call as : POST /push/v1/message , how does it connect with the Content in Content Builder we want to send thorugh this Push, or do we need to send entire message information via this call. I referred the below link, but I am bit confused, with the Json praemeters defined. Thank you in advance.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createPushMessage.htm

Comment: this does not create a message in content builder, this creates a message in Mobile Studio, so it mimics the creation flow located in the UI within mobile studio. If you want to create the push message in Content builder for JB sends you would use the asset routes

Comment: Thank you EazyE